# Word2Vec with a json file

Tags: python, json, gensim, word2vec

So, I have a training data which is in a json file. Now, I am trying to use word Embedding(Word2Vec) on that. However, I have no idea how to proceed. Mostly everything I looked up just deals with direct sentences given and not with json file. Right now all I have done is to read a json file using python.

Please guide me on what could be done next. I trying to use gensim

Comment: Whether txt or json or something else, you need to tokenize your data and then build it into whatever level of ngrams you need for your embedding (pretrained?). Not sure how your json is formatted, but you probably need some preprocessing.

Comment: When you say tokenize does it mean to extract the info under diff labels and store it somewhere (list?)

Comment: Gensim's `Word2Vec` requires texts from a *re-iterable Python sequence* (such as a list or re-startable generator), where each individual item is a *list of string tokens* (the words). A list-of-list-of-strings will work. (It'll can be a little inefficient with larger corpuses, or impractical if the corpus doesn't fit in RAM, but that seems unlikely to be the case if reading data from a single JSON file.) So get your data into a list of texts, where each text is a list of words, and you'll be ready for the next step.

Comment: (And more generally: if at the very beginning of your Python & text-processing learning, work through some other complete tutorials, step by step, also taking extra steps to display for yourself every interim form/change of the data/variables. After that, you'll be familiar with the common steps, like tokenization (breaking texts into the exact words you want to use), & be able to assemble working code from adapted fragments you've already seen work elsewhere, on similar tutorial examples. And if it doesn't work, you'll be able to show in questions here more precisely what you've tried so far.

Comment: Altough it is a single json file however it has multiple json objects in it, and it is quite large. Also I am gonna as you suggested in second comment as that will place me at a better place.